# Erro de configuração na conexão JPA e PostgreSQL

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, jpa

Estou com problemas ao conectar o JPA com PostgreSQL. Acredito que o problema seja na configuração da aplicação.

Estou usando a versão do Java 8, e meu arquivo pom.xml é:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.fsma</groupId>
<artifactId>ControleVenda</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>

<dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.14</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsf-impl</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.14</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
        <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
        <version>5.1</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.faces</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.21</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Hibernate JPA 5.1.0 -->
    <!-- http://hibernate.org/orm/downloads/ -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-java8</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Postgresql Connector -->
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.postgresql/postgresql -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <version>9.4.1208.jre7</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Pool de conexões -->
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-c3p0 -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-c3p0</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- CDI -->
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jboss.weld.servlet/weld-servlet -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.weld.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>weld-servlet</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.3.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- JSTL -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.servlet.jstl</groupId>
        <artifactId>jboss-jstl-api_1.2_spec</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.2.Final</version>
    </dependency>


</dependencies>
```

Em meu arquivo persistence.xml, uso as seguites configurações:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="ControleVenda">


        <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>

        <class>com.fsma.controleVenda.models.Cliente</class>

        <properties>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="org.postgresql.Driver" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:postgresql://172.18.0.2:5432/sis_venda" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="postgres" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="postgres" />

            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect" />
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update" />
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
            <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true" />
            <property name="hibernate.default_schema" value="sis_venda" />
            <property name="hibernate.max_fetch_depth" value="3" />

            <property name="hibernate.c3p0.min_size" value="5" />
            <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_size" value="25" />
            <property name="hibernate.c3p0.timeout" value="120" />
            <property name="hibernate.c3p0.acquire_increment" value="2" />
            <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements"  value="30" />
            <property name="hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period"  value="150" />
            <property name="hibernate.c3p0.preferredTestQuery"  value="select 1" />

        </properties>



    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Criei um JPAUtil.java para complementar a configuração:

```
package com.fsma.controleVenda.dao;

import javax.enterprise.context.RequestScoped;
import javax.enterprise.inject.Disposes;
import javax.enterprise.inject.Produces;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.persistence.Persistence;

public class JPAUtil {

    /**
     * Atributo que pega o nome da conexão do persistence.xml
     */
    private static EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("ControleVenda");

    @Produces
    @RequestScoped
    public EntityManager getEntityManager() {
        return emf.createEntityManager();
    }

    public void close(@Disposes EntityManager em) {
        em.close();
    }

}
```

A StackTrace Retorna os seguintes erros:

```
Cliente [id=null, nome=Yure Menezes, endereco=Rua das Pacas]
nov 25, 2018 6:56:42 PM com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase execute
ADVERTÊNCIA: #{clienteBean.gravar()}: java.lang.NullPointerException
javax.faces.FacesException: #{clienteBean.gravar()}: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:117)
    at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:315)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:786)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1251)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:118)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:593)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:110)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:498)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:169)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:1025)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:445)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1139)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:637)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:318)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: javax.faces.el.EvaluationException: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:101)
    ... 27 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.fsma.controleVenda.dao.ClienteDao.gravar(ClienteDao.java:33)
    at com.fsma.controleVenda.controllers.ClienteBean.gravar(ClienteBean.java:53)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:279)
    at org.apache.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:273)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.el.ForwardingMethodExpression.invoke(ForwardingMethodExpression.java:40)
    at org.jboss.weld.el.WeldMethodExpression.invoke(WeldMethodExpression.java:50)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:105)
    at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:87)
    ... 28 more

nov 25, 2018 6:56:42 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
GRAVE: Servlet.service() for servlet [Faces Servlet] in context with path [/ControleVenda] threw exception [java.lang.NullPointerException] with root cause
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.fsma.controleVenda.dao.ClienteDao.gravar(ClienteDao.java:33)
    at com.fsma.controleVenda.controllers.ClienteBean.gravar(ClienteBean.java:53)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:279)
    at org.apache.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:273)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.el.ForwardingMethodExpression.invoke(ForwardingMethodExpression.java:40)
    at org.jboss.weld.el.WeldMethodExpression.invoke(WeldMethodExpression.java:50)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:105)
    at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:87)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:101)
    at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:315)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:786)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1251)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:118)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:593)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:110)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:498)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:169)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:1025)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:445)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1139)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:637)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:318)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

A minha classe Cliente e Controle ClienteBean, seguem abaixo:

```
package com.fsma.controleVenda.models;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name = "cliente")
public class Cliente {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "nome", length = 100, nullable = false)
    private String nome;

    @Column(name = "endereco", length = 150, nullable = false)
    private String endereco;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getNome() {
        return nome;
    }

    public void setNome(String nome) {
        this.nome = nome;
    }

    public String getEndereco() {
        return endereco;
    }

    public void setEndereco(String endereco) {
        this.endereco = endereco;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + ((endereco == null) ? 0 : endereco.hashCode());
        result = prime * result + ((id == null) ? 0 : id.hashCode());
        result = prime * result + ((nome == null) ? 0 : nome.hashCode());
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        Cliente other = (Cliente) obj;
        if (endereco == null) {
            if (other.endereco != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!endereco.equals(other.endereco))
            return false;
        if (id == null) {
            if (other.id != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!id.equals(other.id))
            return false;
        if (nome == null) {
            if (other.nome != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!nome.equals(other.nome))
            return false;
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Cliente [id=" + id + ", nome=" + nome + ", endereco=" + endereco + "]";
    }




}
```

ClienteBean.java

```
package com.fsma.controleVenda.controllers;

import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.enterprise.context.SessionScoped;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.inject.Inject;

import com.fsma.controleVenda.dao.ClienteDao;
import com.fsma.controleVenda.models.Cliente;

@SessionScoped
@ManagedBean
public class ClienteBean implements Serializable {

    @Inject
    private ClienteDao clienteDao;

    private Cliente cliente;

    private Boolean alterando;



    /**
     * Esse método será executado no momento de instanciação da classe dentro da View
     */
    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        System.out.println("Cliente.init();");

        if (cliente == null) {
            cliente = new Cliente();
        }
    }

    public Cliente getCliente() {
        return cliente;
    }

    public String cadastraCliente() {
        return "CadastraCliente";
    }

    public String voltar() {
        return "cliente";
    }

    public String gravar() {
        this.clienteDao = new ClienteDao();
        System.out.println(cliente.toString());
        clienteDao.gravar(cliente);
        return "index";
    }

}
```

Comment: Poste o código de `ClienteDao`; em especial, a instrução na  linha 33 dentro do método `gravar`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O problema está aqui:

```
#{clienteBean.gravar()}: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Ele está detectando algum valor nulo! Não vai conseguir cadastrar no banco! Pelo que vi você colocou o `id` com *autoincremento*. Então você não pode setar valor para essa variável!

Recomendo criar uma classe principal, criar um objeto cliente e tentar cadastrar assim para ver se retorna algum erro!

Tem que ver esse erro também:

> Servlet.service() for servlet [Faces Servlet] in context with path [/ControleVenda] threw exception [java.lang.NullPointerException] with root cause
>   java.lang.NullPointerException

Se você estiver tentando cadastrar o cliente e juntamente com chave estrangeira no controle de vendas, nunca vai funcionar. Pois o cliente nem possui `id` ainda!